# Can't send Lists from view to controller(Lists Become null)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In one of my projects all of the lists, I try to send from view to controller. Receive as a null in the controller, but in other projects work well.

(there is no problem in code)

For example, I send a list of numbers to the controller but when I trace the code the list is null.

(I'm using asp.net MVC 5.2.7.0)

view:

```
List<DataLayer.Model.Products> groups = ViewBag.Groups;

                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var group in groups.Where(g => g.ParentID == null))
                        {
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedGroups" value="@group.GroupID" /> <span>@group.GroupTitle</span>
                                @if (groups.Any(g => g.ParentID == group.GroupID))
                                {
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach (var subGroup in groups.Where(g => g.ParentID == group.GroupID))
                                        {
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedGroups" value="@subGroup.GroupID" /> <span>@subGroup.GroupTitle</span>
                                            </li>
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                }
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>


  <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success" />
   </div>
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(List<int> selectedGroups)
{
        if (selectedGroups == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorSelectedGroup = true;
                ViewBag.Groups = db.ProductsGroups.ToList();
                return View(model);
            }
}
```

the null error which in if shown
and when I trace the code selectedGroups list is null

Comment: Please include your code and relevant attempts. It is impossible to understand from just text what problem you are encountering.

Comment: code blocks added!

Comment: There should be a code block that includes post operation?

Comment: posting with submit button

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you'll have to add an index to the name attribute of the input.
Something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedGroups[0]" value="@subGroup.GroupID" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedGroups[1]" value="@subGroup.GroupID" />
```

Comment: there is no problem with the code because I used it in other projects and worked well....there is a problem with the project i created